# innobackupex restoring changes root and debian-sys-maint password. mysql restart failed

Tags: mysql, database-backups, percona

I have to set up a backup strategy.
I choosed innobackupex to do so running on Debian 6 Squeeze. There are two servers, The production server and a backup server (that should work if the production server crashes). There is no replication, I use rsync to transfer the backups.
I have a php script that looks in a conf file to know when it have to do backups.

My question is: How the skip the mysql database or the users table with innobackupex ?

On the master : I do the following commands :

```
innobackupex --user=root --password=xxx --no-timestamp /opt/backups/full/

rsync -avz --progress -e 'ssh -i -p 1000 '  /opt/backups/full/ user@xxx:/home/backups/full/
```

this works fine

On the backup server, I have just to prepare and restore the files :

```
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only --user=xxx --password=xxx /home/backups/full/

innobackupex --copy-back /home/backups/full --user=root --password=xxx
```

Everything is alright but on the backup server, the root user's password changed and even the `debian-sys-maint` password.

The root users password becomes the one from the master.

I did a script to correct this. 
The `debian-sys-maint` password is written in clear in the `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` file so a extract it but in php (I use a pdo object) I can't change this password so I can't restart the mysql server.
Sometimes I can't retrieve the password of root user it's not master servers root password.

Sometimes I can stop/start mysql with `/etc/init.d/mysql stop/start`, sometimes with service mysql stop/start it this doesn't works I try with : `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown` (if I could change the password)

If really I can't stop mysql I do `killall mysql` ( I know it's wrong)
and then I change the root password :

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql --user=root mysql
```

Do someone had a problem similar to my ?  How the skip the mysql database with innobackupex ?

Comment: If your tool is unable to preserve the `mysql` system schema, I would recommend dropping this tool and using the `mysqldump` utility provided by MySQL.

Comment: Are you refering to [this tool](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html?id=percona-xtrabackup:innobackupex:start)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innobackupex tool is part of Percona XtraBackup.  I work for Percona and I have developed training on Percona XtraBackup.

There are options for innobackupex to back up specific databases by name or by a regular expression.  @YaK gives one option, or you can see other options here: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/partial_backups_innobackupex.html

However, `--copy-back` assumes you're restoring a full backup to an *empty* datadir.  I.e. if the destination directory is not empty, `--copy-back` will give an error and refuse to overwrite files.

If you are trying to restore InnoDB tables to an instance where you already have a `mysql` database, you'll have to do the restore manually.  This can be as simple as using `mv` of the files into your existing datadir (with the MySQL server shut down of course).  Also remember to use `chown mysql:mysql` on the files before you start mysqld.

PS: You don't need to use `--redo-only` before you restore.  That option is for doing incremental backups, and even then you'd skip that option before you do the final restore.

Comment: Thank you again. 
So finally, I used your advice and also @YaK ones. 
On the master I ignored the mysql database on creating backup
On the slave, I restore it with <code>innobackupex</code> command and copy a clean mysql folder (database) to <code>/var/lib/mysql</code>
It works pretty good.
For XtraBackup, it may be useful to have an option --ignore-databases=xxx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using [this tool](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html?id=percona-xtrabackup%3ainnobackupex%3astart) from Percona.

Then the only helpful option I can find is [`--databases`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_option_reference.html#cmdoption-innobackupex--databases). I will assume you do not want to maintain a list of databases in your script, you can build the list dynamically with a command like this:

```
    shell > mysql [options] -NBe \
            "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema')"
```

You should be able to integrate this call in something like this:

```
    shell > innobackupex \
            --databases=`mysql [options] -NBe \
            "SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema')"`
```

(some extra double quotes may be required, sorry, I do not have access to the tool at this time)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

Yes all my tables are working on InnoDB engine.
Thank you for your advices Bill Karwin, but innobackupex is a great tool, I'll use it for ignoring the mysql database with `--databases`

Yes, I read that `--redo-only` is for incremental, I do incremental too. 
On the master server, I have a directory named `full` and one named `incremental`, after the last incremental, I delete the directories.

After testing, I'll let you know if everything was ok.